# Getting to Shatili village from Tbilisi?

Tags: planning, transportation, georgia-country, tbilisi

I am planning to visit [Shatili](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shatili) with another person in the beginning of May. I know it's possible to get there using a 4×4. What is the approximate price of getting a transfer there from Tbilisi?

Comment: What kind of help? Driving? Navigation? Renting a car?

Comment: Just to add to @Bernhard's comment.  I tried narrowing down your question but you need to give us a starting point.

Comment: From where are you travelling?

Comment: I need transfer from Tbilisi or any other close to Shatili place where 4x4 is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

According to several sites there is no reason to take a 4x4 to Shatili as there are Marshrutkas running from [Tbilisi to Shatili twice a week (Russian)](http://travelgeorgia.ru/89/).

There is also [another site in Russian](http://za7gorami.ru/avtobusy_i_poezda_v_gruzii?page=4) that lists the times as of 2013 for the marshrutkas to Shatili and prices for others so you can guesstimate what this might actually run based on distance and finally [someone who actually been to the village and prices they have paid](http://www.awaytravel.ru/content/%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B8-%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B3-%D1%82%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2) and also the lastly [most sites](http://www.tamartour.ru/georgian-interesting-places/types-of-georgian-interesting-places/historical_places/shatili) suggest hitchhiking to the village.